# How to compare id with the table column values in local database?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Now I need to check `planid` with the table values in local database.

If exists, then it should return `true`.else return `false`.
I am calling this method from the java class and store the value like this.

> boolean plan = dbHandler.IsplanExisted(app_plan_id);

The method in DatabaseModule.java

```
public Boolean IsplanExisted(int planID) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        String qry = "SELECT * FROM " + Table_Plan_App + " WHERE " + 
PAPP_Plan_ID + " = " + "\"" + planID + "\"";
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        if (db.isOpen()) {
            c = db.rawQuery(qry, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            if (c.getCount() > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        } else
            return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("eEmp/DBUserExisted", e.toString());
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (c != null)
            c.close();
        if (db != null)
            db.close();
        ;
    }
}
```

I am comparing my `app_plan_id` with the `PAPP_Plan_ID` in the table.

My problem is method returns always `true` here.

> if (c.getCount() > 0)
>                       return true;

Why?

I am new to android. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> if (c.getCount() > 0) return true;
> ```
>
> Why ?

Because, your table has atleast 1 row and [`c.getCount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount()) return the total number of row count.

Comment: but there is no row. even though c.getCount>0 returns true@Ravi

Answer (score 0):

**I believe that the code you have shown will return the correct result and that the issue you have is with your subsequent code**; as per your comment :-

> but there is no row. even though c.getCount>0 returns true

For testing purposes I used :-

### DBHelper2.java :-

public class DBHelper2 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String DBNAME = "planning";
public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
public static final String Table_Plan_App = "planapp";
public static final String PAPP_Plan_ID = "planpp_id";
public static final String other_column = "planapp_other";

public DBHelper2(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.d("ONCREATE","Initiated");
    String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Table_Plan_App +
            "(" +
            PAPP_Plan_ID + " INTEGER, " +
            other_column + " TEXT" +
            ")";
    Log.d("ONCREATE","Createing table using SQL " +crtsql);
    db.execSQL(crtsql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public long insertPlan(int id, String other) {
    long rv = -1;
    SQLiteDatabase db =  this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(PAPP_Plan_ID,id);
    cv.put(other_column,other);
    rv = db.insert(Table_Plan_App,null,cv);
    db.close();
    return rv;
}

public Boolean IsplanExisted(int planID) {
    String tag = "ISPLANEXISTED";
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        String qry = "SELECT * FROM " + Table_Plan_App + " WHERE " +
                PAPP_Plan_ID + " = " + "\"" + planID + "\"";
        Log.d(tag,"Generated query is " + qry);
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Log.d(tag,"Readable Database obtained.");
        if (db.isOpen()) {
            Log.d(tag,"Database is open.");
            c = db.rawQuery(qry, null);
            String[] columns = c.getColumnNames();
            for (String s: columns
                 ) {
                Log.d(tag,"Column " + s);

            }
            Log.d(tag,"Query completed");
            c.moveToFirst();
            Log.d(tag,"Moved to fist attempt completed.");
            Log.d(tag, "Cursor row count is " + c.getCount());
            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                Log.d(tag, "Returning True");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.d(tag,"Returning false as count is not greater than 0.");
                return false;
            }
        } else
            Log.d(tag,"Oooops Database is not open.");
            return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("eEmp/DBUserExisted", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        Log.d(tag,"Closing Cursor and Database in Finally construct.");
        if (c != null)
            c.close();
        if (db != null)
            db.close();
        ;
    }
}
```

}

#### Notes

- Lots of logging/debugging code added to the `IsplanExisted` method, otherwise the code for `IsplanExisted` is identical.

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        DBHelper2 dbhlp2 = new DBHelper2(this);
        boolean result;
        // First delete all rows from table
        dbhlp2.getWritableDatabase().delete(DBHelper2.Table_Plan_App,null,null);

        // Try with no rows in table
        result = dbhlp2.IsplanExisted(100);
        Log.d("TESTRESULT", "Result from IsplaneExpired(ID 100 table empty) was " + String.valueOf(result));

        // Add a row with id as 12
        dbhlp2.insertPlan(12,"test1");

        // Check for row with id of 20 (shouldn't be one)
        result = dbhlp2.IsplanExisted(20);
        Log.d("TESTRESULT", "Result from IsplaneExpired(ID 20 no such row) was " + String.valueOf(result));
        // Check for row with id 12 (should exist)
        result = dbhlp2.IsplanExisted(12);
        Log.d("TESTRESULT", "Result from IsplaneExpired(ID 12 should exist) was " + String.valueOf(result));

    }
}
```

#### Notes

- gets instance of **`DBHelper2`** then uses the **`IsPlanExisted`** method writing debugging info to the log.

### Results :-

#### Part 1 - Empty table so no rows - returns false as expected.

```
02-02 21:54:32.530 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Generated query is SELECT * FROM planapp WHERE planpp_id = "100"
02-02 21:54:32.530 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Readable Database obtained.
02-02 21:54:32.530 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Database is open.
02-02 21:54:32.530 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Column planpp_id
02-02 21:54:32.530 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Column planapp_other
02-02 21:54:32.530 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Query completed
02-02 21:54:32.530 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Moved to fist attempt completed.
02-02 21:54:32.530 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Cursor row count is 0
02-02 21:54:32.530 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Returning false as count is not greater than 0.
02-02 21:54:32.530 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Closing Cursor and Database in Finally construct.
02-02 21:54:32.530 1782-1782/? D/TESTRESULT: Result from IsplaneExpired(ID 100 table empty) was false
```

#### Part 2 - After adding a row with id 12 looking for id 20 - false as expected.

```
02-02 21:54:32.534 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Generated query is SELECT * FROM planapp WHERE planpp_id = "20"
02-02 21:54:32.538 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Readable Database obtained.
02-02 21:54:32.538 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Database is open.
02-02 21:54:32.538 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Column planpp_id
02-02 21:54:32.538 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Column planapp_other
02-02 21:54:32.538 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Query completed
02-02 21:54:32.538 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Moved to fist attempt completed.
02-02 21:54:32.538 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Cursor row count is 0
02-02 21:54:32.538 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Returning false as count is not greater than 0.
02-02 21:54:32.538 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Closing Cursor and Database in Finally construct.
02-02 21:54:32.538 1782-1782/? D/TESTRESULT: Result from IsplaneExpired(ID 20 no such row) was false
```

#### Part 3 - Looking for row with id 12 - Found as expected.

```
02-02 21:54:32.538 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Generated query is SELECT * FROM planapp WHERE planpp_id = "12"
02-02 21:54:32.538 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Readable Database obtained.
02-02 21:54:32.538 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Database is open.
02-02 21:54:32.538 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Column planpp_id
02-02 21:54:32.542 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Column planapp_other
02-02 21:54:32.542 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Query completed
02-02 21:54:32.542 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Moved to fist attempt completed.
02-02 21:54:32.542 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Cursor row count is 1
02-02 21:54:32.542 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Returning True
02-02 21:54:32.542 1782-1782/? D/ISPLANEXISTED: Closing Cursor and Database in Finally construct.
02-02 21:54:32.542 1782-1782/? D/TESTRESULT: Result from IsplaneExpired(ID 12 should exist) was true
```

---

### A simpler/condensed alternative

The `IsplanExisted` could be simplified to something like :-

```
public boolean IsplanExisted(int planID) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query(
            Table_Plan_App,
            null,
            PAPP_Plan_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(planID)},
            null,null,null
    );
    int count = c.getCount();
    c.close();
    return count > 0;
}
```

#### Notes

- getReadableDatabase will generally return a writeable database, so might as well always use getWriteableDatabase as per :-

> Create and/or open a database. This will be the same object returned
>   by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk,
>   requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a
>   read-only database object will be returned. If the problem is fixed, a
>   future call to getWritableDatabase() may succeed, in which case the
>   read-only database object will be closed and the read/write object
>   will be returned in the future. [getReadableDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase%28%29)

- There is no real need to close a database in a simple App, so the `db.close` has been left out. Cursors though should be closed when done with.
- Instead of `rawQuery` the convenience (generally preferred) `query` has been used. This builds the query, it will escape characters as required (*PS there is no need to enclose the ID in quotes*).
- The third parameter is the WHERE clause less WHERE. It can include paramterised arguments using a **`?`**, which are then specified by the fourth parameter a String array of the arguments/values to be used.
- See [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)